# encrypt app.config connectionStrings without decryption

Tags: c#, visual-studio, encryption, app-config, aspnet-regiis.exe

I know this may be an old question, and there are a lot of discussion about this issue, but all answers do not help me because there are decrypt method as well 
I want to encrypt app.config file so no one can see my stringConnections 
I know using

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" <"path">
```

after changing app.config to web.config and renaming it again after encryption
**but as it's Windows Application that means encrypted app.config will be within app directory 

so, everyone who can access it, which is simply everyone can always decrypt it using**

```
aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionStrings" <"path"> <br>
```

so, how can I protect it somehow that no one can decrypt it, and only my app can use it

Comment: You can't have it both ways. Either your app can decrypt it and use it, *and* potentially anyone who has access to the directory can decrypt it, *or* no one (including your app) can decrypt it. You might be able to have it encrypted with a key that only your app knows, but having access to the directory merely makes this an inconvenience for an attacker. As long as you assume physical access, it's marginal protection at best.

Comment: What about not using the `app.config` to store your connection string? The point of storing it in `app.config` is to allow a change without having to recompile the entire application, or to allow you just taking a look to check if the connection string is correct, in case of something not working as expected. If no one can decrypt it, there is no sense in storing it in `app.config`, just fix in your code.

Comment: @Alisson that's a good point, but I'm using entity model, that by default it stores string connection in app.config.. is there a way that I can use entity model and store connection string somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

**Bad news**: You got yourself into trouble here because the place you have chosen is accessible to both your app and all people and apps with access to the same location. This means: if your connection strings are decrypt-able by your app, everyone else can with access to the encrypted data.

**Good news**: I had the same issue and solved it by changing the location of where my configuration data was located, including my connection strings. I moved the information from the web.config into a configuration service. This way my application had access to the service, like every other app and person, but only my app could provide the correct authentication.

**In essence**: encryption/decryption may not be the solution you need, but authorization is an alternative: restrict access.

Comment: Thanks for explanations, now it's clear that using either encrypted or decrypted string connection in app.config or web.config is not recommended, now my question is can I use that configuration service with Windoes Form or WPF because i'm using windows application and entity model, so by default it stores string connection in app.config

Comment: What technology you use has nothing to do with it so yes, you can use a Web service to store your connection information. Only condition is you have access to that service. Your connection string will not be stored in your app.config anymore, it will be stored in (via) your Web service.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, that's really helpful, the app also will know better weather there's internet connection or not so no need to try internet connection via connecting to database!